# How to re-index a series?

Tags: series-expansion, expression-manipulation

I'm trying to implement Frobenius method of solving ODEs in Mathematica, namely make a general routine to get recurrence relations from a given equation. Currently I'm stuck at re-indexing a series (to make same powers under single summation sign).

Consider for example the following series:

```
Sum[r^(2 + k)*c[k], {k, 0, Infinity}]
```

I'm trying to change `k` index to `m-n` (in this example `n=2`) it so that it looked like this:

```
Sum[r^m*c[m-2], {m, 2, Infinity}]
```

Here's my incomplete attempt:

```
Sum[r^(2 + k)*c[k], {k, 0, Infinity}] //. 
  {Sum[(a_)*r^(k + (n_)), {k, 0, Infinity}] :> Sum[a*r^(k + n), {k, 0, Infinity}] /.
     k -> m - n}
```

For some reason it doesn't appear to change the expression at all...

So my question is: how do I implement re-indexing of a series correctly?

Comment: I would recommend using a fake `Head` like `sum` instead of `Sum`, to keep from long, fruitless evaluations where *Mathematica* tries to perform the sum. You can always do `sum -> Sum` later on. The big problem is that `/.
     k -> m - n` is tacked on afterwars. I think you want this: `sum[r^(2 + k)*c[k], {k, 0, 
   Infinity}] //. {sum[(a_)*r^(k + (n_Integer)), {k, 0, 
     Infinity}] :> (sum[a*r^(k + n), {k, 0, Infinity}] /. k -> m - n)}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problems are that the `Sum` in the `Rule` evaluates, and even if it didn't evaluate, the pattern in the rule is too specific. I would use something like:

```
Sum[r^(2+k)*c[k],{k,0,Infinity}] /. 
    Verbatim[Sum][a_, {k_, k0_, Infinity}] :> 
    Sum[a /. k->k-n, {k, k0+n, Infinity}] //TeXForm
```

> $\sum _{k=n}^{\infty } c(k-n) r^{k-n+2}$

Answer (score 5):

Along the lines suggested by @march in a comment:

```
expr = Sum[r^(2 + k)*c[k], {k, 0, Infinity}];

expr /. {Sum -> foo, {k, b_, e_, i___} :> {m, 2 + b, 2 + e, i}, k -> m - 2} /. foo -> Sum
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 5):

You may reindex by first principles.

1. Change of variables in the term.
2. Solve for new bounds.

```
reindexSum[sum_Sum, change_Rule, var_Symbol] :=
 Module[{term = First@sum, bounds},
  term = term /. change;
  bounds = 
   var /. 
    First@Solve[Equal @@ change, var] /. 
    Partition[MapThread[Rule, {List @@ change[[{1, 1}]], sum[[2, 2 ;;]]}], 1];
  Sum[term, {var, Sequence @@ bounds}]
  ]
```

Then

```
reindexSum[
 Sum[r^(2 + k)*c[k], {k, 0, Infinity}],
 k -> m - 2,
 m
 ]
```

> ```
> Sum[r^m*c[-2 + m], {m, 2, Infinity}]
> ```

Hope this helps.